# The best way to override [gs]et for javascript object instance (with prototype?)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sample code how do I want the instance to work:

```
var brother = new Person("James");

console.log(brother.status);
// "James, current location: home, health condition: saber"

brother.status = {
    location: "pub",
    "health condition": "drunk as a skunk"
};

console.log(brother.status);
// "James, current location: pub, health condition: drunk as a skunk"
```

Question is how to program object Person, its prototype and how to use Object.defineProperty to achieve this (or similar) behavior the most elegant way.

I did some solution so far but I would like to not to explain it here to bother your mind with it.

The key answer should contain Object with methods and properties that are not copied for each instance and Object must be easy to inherit.

Comment: for the sake of whoever has to maintain this code should you ever be hit by a bus, please dont do this.  (people who write code like this are statistically more likely to be hit by busses)

Comment: @Robert Levy the only maintainer ever will be me. And I'm fully aware that gset override might be strongly counterintuitive. But there are few rare cases when it is exactly opposite.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Constructor
function Person(name){
  // In prototype, Can be in herited
  this._name = name;
  this._status;

  // Not available in prototype, hence cannot be inherited
  age = 20;
  function incAge(){
    age++;
  }
  // Available in instances, Privilege.  
  this.getAge = function(){
     incAge();  // Accessing private members
     return age;
  }
}

Person.prototype.constructor = Person;

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "status", {
  configurable : true,  // If you want it to be changed in derived class
  enumerable : false,
  get : function(){
    this._status = this._status || {location : "home", "health condition" : "saber"};
    return this._name + ", current location: "+ this._status.location+", health condition: "+this._status["health condition"];
  },
  set : function(status){this._status = status}
});

//----DERIVED CLASS---  
function SuperPerson(name){
  Person.call(this, name);          
}

SuperPerson.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
SuperPerson.prototype.constructor = SuperPerson;

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "status", {
  enumerable : false,
  get : function(){
    this._status = this._status || {location : "BatCave", "health condition" : "I dont have parents to take care of me"};
    return this._name + ", current location: "+ this._status.location+", health condition: "+this._status["health condition"];
  }
});
```

[This post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) beautifully explained the descriptors of the Object.defineProperty method, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a common private `defaultStatus` for all people, and then for each person create a private `status` which inherits from `defaultStatus`. Then, expose a public `status` which, on setting, assigns the new data to the private `status` (I use ES6 [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)). On getting, it builds the desired string.

```js
var Person = (function() {
  var defaultStatus = {
    location: 'home',
    health: 'saber'
  };
  return function Person(name) {
    var status = Object.create(defaultStatus);
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'status', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: function() {
        return [
          name,
          "current location: " + status.location,
          "health condition: " + status.health
        ].join(', ');
      },
      set: Object.assign.bind(void 0, status)
    });
  };
})();
```

Comment: Upvote for Object.assign and string concatenation performance consideration